# Multiply an expression by the inverse of the Big-Oh term in a series expansion

Tags: series-expansion

Simple example to illustrate what I want

```
Series[J[x]/(x^2 (1 - x^2)^2), {x, 0, -5}]
```

returns

```
O[x]^{-2}
```

Now I want to somehow take the above result and multiply my function by its inverse - i.e. something like

```
(J[x]/(x^2 (1 - x^2)^2)*Function_that_gets_rid_of_the_O[%]^{-1}
```

Is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One think that can be done is

```
singCoeff[y_, a_, func_] := 
  Switch[TrueQ[# < 0], True, (y - a)^-#, False, 1] & @ 
   Exponent[
    Series[Flatten[func], {y, a, -20}] /. 
     SeriesData[x1_, a1_, a2_, e_, a3_, a4_] :> (x1 - a1)^e, y - a];
```

Then

```
Off[SeriesData::sdatc];
singCoeff[x, 1, J[x]/(x^2 (1 - x^2)^2)]
On[SeriesData::sdatc];
```

produces

```
(-1 + x)^2
```

and the `Off` and and `On` commands are to get rid of an annoying message about something not being a `List`, due to the `FullForm` of `Series`.
If one wants to apply the above function to a list of expressions, `@` should be changed to `/@`